# Discord.py Bot is sending an extra message after each restart

Tags: python, discord

I'm working on a basic Discord.py bot. Currently, I have a few commands, but as I seem to run it each time, and run another command it adds a new response. All I want it to do is have one reply per command.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands



client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')

@client.command()
async def logon(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'You are now On-Duty!')

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms')
```

I expect the output after entering command ".logon" and ".ping" to be 1x Output, not multiple.

Comment: Is it possible that there are multiple instances of the script running?

Comment: possibly, I'm kinda new, not too sure. I haven't stopped the script, or anything. 
Could you help? Im using Atom

Comment: Simple test: reboot the machine, see if the problem is gone.

Comment: machine meaning computer, correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this in command line make sure you are not running 2 instances of the script. You can check this by using task manger or command line.

```
tasklist /v | findstr /c:"python.exe"
```

Then a `Taskkill /PID {PID_HERE}` You can add a `/F` at the end to force close it.

You can also do what Klaus D. mentioned a full restart of your computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't figure the problem out, go to [Discord Application Manager](https://discord.com/developers/applications), click on your bot, then click on Bot, then click on regenerate Token and copy it into your code where the token goes, then you have fixed your problem. This happened to me and I just replaced the token and it stopped.